# Indenting every second row of a table without affecting the first rows. html/css/js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table full of data. Every second row is a child row of every first row. So each child row is hidden until I click the parent row. The child rows then fadeIn below the parents with jQuery.

How would I indent the child rows beneath the parent rows so they are clearly child nodes to the parents?

Ive tried adding small  elements to the child rows but that just doesnt look right. It ends up crushing the first rows when I expand out the second rows.

I hope this doesnt sound like jibberish...

```
//HTML & CSS
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="clickDiv3"></th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th></th>
       <td class="showThird">Peter</td>
       <td class="showThird">Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th></th>
       <td class="showThird">Lois</td>
       <td class="showThird">Griffin</td>
    </tr>
</table>


  //JS
  $("#clickDiv3").click(function(){
      $(".showThird").slideDown(".500").fadeIn(".200");
  });
```

Any help or advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: How do you know there is a relationship between these rows?

Comment: does that really matter? If you can't suggest anything helpful, maybe don't post anything.

Comment: It *does* matter.  If there is a relationship between the rows, it needs to be expressed in the markup, not just with visual appearances.  If you want real help, maybe you should post data that's actually representative of what you're doing.  As it stands, tables look like the wrong markup because you're looking to express a parent/child relationship (which tables aren't really for).

Comment: Can you comment your HTML to explicitly show which rows/cells should be 'indented'? And, incidentally, from what little information we can see in your HTML it looks like a `dl` might be the more appropriate mark-up.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can't exactly do that with tables but you can try this:

```
table tr:nth(3) td {
    padding-left : 10px;
}
```

But if you don't have so many columns, you can simply use ul instead of table for such usage. Take a look at http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tree-menu-framework

Comment: I was worried someone was gonna say that. It seems like it might be a common issue, indenting child rows should be pretty common no?

Comment: Why would it be common?

Comment: Indenting child rows below parents makes sense. Not in every situation but in some.

Comment: It's not common because such a structure is a tree not a plain table. Have a look at the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works cross-browser (only tested in Chrome). All cells on even rows will be indented (and overflow the table width):

```
tr:nth-child(2n) td {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3KJdX/

But you should listen to the advice the other users are giving you: maybe a table is not the right structure for your data.